# Import PostgreSQL with Sqoop in Docker

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, docker, sqoop, hortonworks-sandbox

I have a PostgreSQL DB sitting on my local machine (Windows) and I would like to import it into my Hortonworks Sandbox using Apache Sqoop. While something like [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/14802/sqoop-importexport-tutorial.html) sounds great, the complicating factor is that my Sandbox is sitting in a Docker container, so statements such as `sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/ambari --username ambari -P` seem to run into authentication errors. I believe the issue comes from trying to connect to the local host from inside the docker container.

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?answertab=votes#tab-top) on connecting to a MySQL DB from within a container and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database) to try to use PostgreSQL instead, but have so far been unsuccessful. I have tried connecting to '127.0.0.1' and '172.17.0.1' (the host's IP) in order to connect to my local host from within Docker. I have also adjusted PostgreSQL's configuration file to listen for connections on all IP addresses. However, I still get the following error messages when I run `sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:5432/<db_name> --username postgres -P` (where `<ip>` is either `127.0.0.1` or `172.17.0.1`, and `<db_name>` is the name of my database)

For connecting with `127.0.0.1`:

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

For connecting with `172.17.0.1`:

```
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for local testing and not for production level coding, you can enable all trusted connections to your database by updating the `pg_hba.conf` file

1. Locate your `pg_hba.conf` file inside your postgres `data` directory
2. Vim the file and update it with the following lines:

   `#TYPE    DATABASE   USER   ADDRESS     METHOD
    local    all        all                trust
    host     all        all    0.0.0.0/0   trust
    host     all        all    ::1/128     trust`
3. Restart your postgres service

If you do this, your first use case (using `127.0.0.1`) should work

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that I'm doing this on Windows, which means the local/all/all/trust doesn't work (see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846363/postgresql-9-2-4-windows-7-service-wont-start-could-not-load-pg-hba-conf))